# how to use "preconnect" and "dns-prefetch" with Axios

Tags: axios, google-chrome-devtools, pagespeed, nuxt.js

how can i fix this with Axios, Are there any parameters ?

```
axios.get('/slug', { params })
```

> Preconnect to required origins
>   Consider adding `preconnect` or `dns-prefetch` resource hints to establish early connections to important third-party origins. Learn more.

[image]

why chrome audit declares this opportunity when this url does not exist in the source code

https://immobiliere-essaouira.graines-digitales.fr/

Comment: How do we achieve this functionality in react native apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All [resource hints](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/resource-hints) can be used only as attributes on a `<link>` element. You can read about what they do and how for example [here](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/resource-hints#preconnect)

So there is nothing you can do directly in JavaScript (except of course adding the attribute to existing link dynamically based on user action)

If your are requesting something using Axios from domain `https://api.my-app.com`, just including `<link rel="preconnect" href="https://api.my-app.com" />` into your page should be enough...

Comment: Sorry my request was not complete. I updated the initial post. Thanks for your feedback.